# Magento2 import csv and delete existing value for column special_price

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I use Magento CSV import/export functionality in order to import and export stocks and pricing regularly and it works perfectly.

But I do not how to remove an existing "**special_price**" by using the CSV file. If I pass "**NULL**", will the special price becomes **0**?

Can anyone help me? Please!

Comment: you want special price to be update or delete all price from product?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want to delete all existing special price from the CSV import functionality.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same issue and it's actually quite easy to solve. Magento CSV import allows you to unset the value of an attribute by putting the **Empty attribute value constant** in the column value. In most case it is `__EMPTY__VALUE__` as in import setting [image: as can be seen in the screenshot]

My sample CSV structure is like this:

[image]

Comment: You have to set import behavior to "Add/Update" for this to work.

Comment: Only Available in 2.3.x

Comment: @khuenq Nice answer

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you , you have just to choose Import Behavior 'replace',
and left 'special_price , special_price_from_date , special_price_to_date' empty with value inside csv

Answer (score 1):

If the import file includes all the catalog/products you have on website, or you can filter priducts with common criteria,then you cans use mass update as a workaround in order to unset special price. After that import your file so only given special prices will be updated.

[image]

[image]