# Magento 2 Not Removing Product Special Price by importing CSV

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2, php-7

I am trying to remove the special price of my product by the import CSV. Tried Several Ways.
By adding "0" in the column. Also tried to import with Empty Column. But nothing happened.

Comment: you want to only remove special price all products ???

Comment: Yes, I want to remove the special price by CSV import.

Comment: you want to other way ??? If yes check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/195009/85907

Comment: Yes, It is working in that way. But I want to update it from the CSV.

Comment: which filed you insert in csv???

Comment: sku special_price special_price_from_date special_price_to_date

Comment: i am not sure but you try only two columns like :- `sku and special_price`  and special_price columns value add 0

Comment: Tried both cases. but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it vis csv
in the csv import page there is a line

**Empty attribute value constant**

which by default has this value

```
__EMPTY__VALUE__
```

if you use this as your special_price value it will remove it on the import